# Get child element contents in an array from class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to get all img src from the class "photo-grid-item".

`<a href="/photo/CIJXEU9VRY" class="photo-grid-item">`

`<img src="someimage.jpg" width="420" height="280" alt="man woman">`

`</a>`

`<a href="/photo/125255" class="photo-grid-item">`

`<img src="another.jpg" width="420" height="280" alt="man woman">`

`</a>`

I have tried

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".photo-grid-item")).filter(el=>el.nextElementSibling.src)`

What I need is

[someimage.jpg,another.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const resultArray = [];

const photoGridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-grid-item');

photoGridItems.forEach(photoGridItem => {
  let photoGridItemImage = photoGridItem.querySelector('img');
  resultArray.push(photoGridItemImage.src)
})

console.log(resultArray)
```

```html
<a href="/photo/CIJXEU9VRY" class="photo-grid-item">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" width="420" height="280" alt="man woman">
</a>
<a href="/photo/125255" class="photo-grid-item">
  <img src="another.jpg" width="420" height="280" alt="man woman">
</a>
```